# Set expiration date in Google drive does not show in the API

Tags: google-drive-api

We are working will Google's API and we were looking for a field for the new feature- Set an expiration date for file sharing (http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2016/03/set-expiration-dates-for-access-to.html), but could not find anything in the json file.
Is this field documented? Are you going to add it in the future? 
If not, can we ask for it? It will be a big help since this feature really mitigates sharing issues our customers may have.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to say that that only refers to the Google Drive website it doesn't say anything about the API.  Second it was posed on Posted: 3/15/2016 and says Gradual rollout (2–3 months for feature visibility).   Which means that at the earliest everyone will have it on June 15 2016.  This is again on the website.

There is no mention of it in the documentation for the API so I think you will have to assume at least for now that this is a website only feature and not something that will be available in the API

I would add it as an feature request on the [issue forum](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=API%3DDrive)